# Karate UI: Not able to run Karate UI tests from Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, karate

I am trying to run run my UI tests using Karate-chrome docker in Jenkins. It is giving the following error:-

```
08:36:49  SEVERE: driver config / start failed: http call failed after 2 milliseconds for url: http://localhost:9222/json, options: {type=chrome, showDriverLog=true, start=true, executable=/usr/bin/google-chrome, target=null}
08:36:49  com.intuit.karate.KarateException: http call failed after 2 milliseconds for url: http://localhost:9222/json
08:36:49    at com.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioEngine.httpInvokeOnce(ScenarioEngine.java:599)
08:36:49    at com.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioEngine.httpInvoke(ScenarioEngine.java:558)
08:36:49    at com.intuit.karate.Http.method(Http.java:83)
08:36:49    at com.intuit.karate.Http.method(Http.java:92)
08:36:49    at com.intuit.karate.Http.get(Http.java:100)
08:36:49  Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:9222 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

I have used the karate-chrome docker image and tried with explicitly giving executable path as well, nothing seems to work.
configure driver = { type: 'chrome', showDriverLog: true, start: true, executable: '/usr/bin/google-chrome' }

This is run within an Intuit Jenkins server.
Peter Thomas, request your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because of a recent change to Chrome that requires an extra command-line option. This issue should give you a workaround: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/2275#issuecomment-1463882328

We should release 1.4.0.RC4 shortly that will include this by default.

Let us know if that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. That did not work. I am getting the same error. It is a HttpConnectionException that it is throwing.  SEVERE: driver config / start failed: http call failed after 2 milliseconds for url: http://localhost:9222/json, options: {type=chrome, showDriverLog=true, start=true, addOptions=["--remote-allow-origins=*"], target=null}
20:58:02  com.intuit.karate.KarateException: http call failed after 2 milliseconds for url: http://localhost:9222/json

Comment: @donny then it must be something in your environment and I don't have the answer. you can refer these threads if they help. please post back your findings: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/2193 | https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bkarate%5D+docker+connect

Comment: I finally managed to get this working by providing the new headless option for chrome headless=new. configure driver = { type: 'chrome', addOptions: ['--no-sandbox', '--headless=new', '--remote-allow-origins=*', '--disable-extensions', '--disable-dev-shm-usage', '--disable-notifications' ], showDriverLog: true, showProcessLog: true, userDataDir: null  }. Also, after going past that stage, our angular js(app fabric) app was not loading and finally worked after '--disable-notifications'  option.

Comment: Starting with Chrome 96 version, chrome team has launched this new headless mode and in the latest versions (probably from version 109), old headless mode does not seem to work.

Comment: @donny thanks, I added a comment here: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/2275