# Karate DSL: Getting java.net.SocketTimeoutException when feature file is executed from jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, karate

Getting java.net.SocketTimeoutException when karate feature file is executed from jenkins pipeline but it is working fine when executed from local machine. I have also discussed this with devops team and they mentioned that this is not an issue with jenkins as some of the tests are passed (around 20%). They mentioned that all tests should be failed if it was due to an env issue.

Checked through logs and not able to found out any root cause

Comment: well another team reported this here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75740474/143475  - and I have commented there, and can't think of any other ideas. if you mean UI tests, note that there is a rare config you can try: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-core#configure-driver - look for `timeout` (try that first) and `httpConfig`

Comment: I am facing this issue in API tests. I tried executing my tests in another env from Jenkins and it worked fine. I guess issue is related to test env. Thanks for the inputs.